# How to refer to the child elements of User Control by name, not by index?

Tags: c#, user-controls, intellisense

There are 2 User Controls (names in the picture). I need to access the child controls inside the main User Contol and change their properties from anywhere in the program.

At the moment, I change the properties of the child controls by getting the names through a loop. (But as you can see, the reference is made using **indexes**, while I would like to use **names** that would be displayed in IntelliSense).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add(((UC_NumericUpDown)uC_Main1.Controls[3]).Value = 12); // uC_Numeric1
        listBox1.Items.Add((uC_Main1.Controls[3].Controls[1]).BackColor = Color.Blue); // divider1
        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < uC_Main1.Controls.Count; i++) {
            listBox1.Items.Add(uC_Main1.Controls[i].Name);
        }

        listBox1.Items.Add(((UC_NumericUpDown)uC_Main1.Controls[3]).Value = 55); // uC_Numeric1
        listBox1.Items.Add((uC_Main1.Controls[3].Controls[1]).BackColor = Color.Red); // divider1
    }
```

[image]

Here is an example with changing properties after pressing buttons:

[image]

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes. Your advice to "make the control public", was very helpful, it's much better than creating a whole bunch of properties, for each control and the data is easier to get/change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Controls` collection also has an indexer accepting a string: `Controls["the name"].BackColor`. The disadvantage is that this returns a control unspecifically typed as `Control`. You must cast it to more specific types to access specialised properties.

But you could also make the controls public and access them directly. You can change the access to a control in the properties window by changing the `Modifiers` property in the "Design" section (in WnForms). This changes the C# access modifier of the control variable (field).

This allows you a strongly typed access to these controls.